# Как в FPDF вывести в документ кириллицу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fpdf

Как в FPDF вывести в документ кириллицу? Никакие ухищрения с `encode/decode` не привели к желаемому результату. Код:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'Roboto-Light.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Заявка №_01-000001", ln=1, align="C")
pdf.output("simple_demo.pdf")
```

Всегда приводит к ошибке:

```
    p = self.pages[n].encode("latin1") if PY3K else self.pages[n]
```

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 51-56: ordinal not in range(256)

А если попытаться сделать вот так:

```
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Заявка №_01-000001".encode('latin-1', 'replace').decode('latin-1'), ln=1, align="C")
```

... то получим в документе крякозябры.

Кто сталкивался?

Comment: Ты не прописал путь к шрифтам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно проблема в том, что выбранный шрифт не поддерживает unicode.

1. Нужны шрифрты [Free Unicode TrueType font pack for FPDF](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/releases)
2. Пример кода

   ```
   pdf = FPDF()
   pdf.add_page()
   pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
   pdf.set_font('DejaVu', '', 14)
   pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Заявка №_01-000001", ln=1, align="C")
   pdf.output("simple_demo.pdf")
   ```

Более подробный [пример](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Unicode/index.html)